# Does XYZPrinting software allow the creation of rafts when printing?

Tags: 3d-models, software

Ironing out all my worries before buying my first 3D printer.

I'm looking at getting the ***da Vinci miniMaker*** 3D printer as my first 3D printer, but it doesn't come with a heated bed.

On my previous question about [heating beds effect on a print](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3189/non-heated-beds-affect-on-3d-prints), I was told that I need to use a raft to compensate for the absence of a heated bed. What I want to know is, does the software that comes with the printer allow the creation of rafts whilst/prior to printing? Or will it create rafts if need be?

Comment: Or is there another software that can be used with the Da Vinci printer, that will allow me to create rafts for my prints?

Comment: 2 years ago I had a prebuilt German Rep Rep Neo in the past and after 2 months problems occurred, so I sold it very cheap. Now I've bought a cheaper assembly kit of a Prusa i3 model and I feel much more confident to cope with occurring problems because I know how to assemble and disassemble. I recommend you to also start with a assembly kit.

Comment: It had crossed my mind when I was looking at various 3D Printing Options. But I didn't pay too close attention to DIY Models, mainly because I think I will have a bad time assembling it. Dont get me wrong here, the price is cheaper than a pre-built, the build size is SOOO much more better, and the frame is steel, which is a plus in my books, but when it comes to assembiling the printer for use, Im gonna have a bad time

Comment: Would you, in your opinion, say that assembling the Prusa i3 was relatively simple?

Comment: I would say a raft is more of a band-aid fix for not having a heated bed rather than a way to "compensate". It's nowhere near as good.

Comment: Yea. Thats why I'm really considering the Prusa i3 now. At least that comes with a heating bed. No more rafts :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After watching some YouTube Videos, I would take it that the abovementioned software does include the option to create rafts when printing a model.

Comment: Maybe you could include some details on how to enable raft generation in the XYZprinting software, for the benefit of those who google the question and end up on this site? As it stands, your answer is rather unhelpful for somebody trying to get XYZprinting software to create a raft.

Comment: Ok. From what I saw on YouTube, there is an option when selecting print in the software. A window will pop up for you to choose your printer, and on the side, in another window for you to select whether you want to add rafts